# Gatling localAddresses causes timeouts

Tags: scala, azure, networking, gatling

We would like to be able to cycle through the available IP addresses on an Azure virtual machine we have set up for running our performance tests.

Our protocol code which just uses the main local host address works fine:

```
    var httpProtocol = io.gatling.http.Predef.http
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .acceptHeader("*/*")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36")
    .maxConnectionsPerHostLikeChrome
```

However, when we change this to try and cycle through the available IPs (configured on the NIC and pingable) we get a large number of errors "i.n.c.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: blah.mydomain.co.uk/11.22.33.44:443" (although the first one or two users seem OK):

```
val localIpAddresses = Seq("1.2.3.4",
                               "1.2.3.5",
                               "1.2.3.6"
                              );
httpProtocol = io.gatling.http.Predef.http
     .baseUrl(baseUrl)
     .inferHtmlResources()
     .acceptHeader("*/*")
     .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36")
     .localAddresses(localIpAddresses:_*)
     .maxConnectionsPerHostLikeChrome
```

Both go on to use this code:

```
    setUp(usertype1.inject(
                rampConcurrentUsers(0) to (maxConcurrentUsers) during (rampUpDownTime),
                constantConcurrentUsers(maxConcurrentUsers) during (mainTestTime),
                rampConcurrentUsers(maxConcurrentUsers) to (0) during (rampUpDownTime)
            )
        ).protocols(httpProtocol);
```

What could be causing these timeouts when we're using different IPs on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

Can only be a network issue (routing, firewall, etc...), not a Gatling one.